# Está gerando este erro quando tento gerar a migration no EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Quando tento digitar o comando, Add-Migration InitialDB -Context SistemaTarefasDBContex, sempre gera este erro:

Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.NETCore.App.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64', version: '6.0.24'
path: 'System.Private.CoreLib.dll'

Já estou com o NET 6.0 e 7.0 instalado no meu desktop, inclusive o EF está na última versão, fiquei na dúvida se ele seria compatível com o projeto pois ele se encontra na versão 6.0.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyiCH.png)
Alguma sugestão?
Obrigado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A versão da lib EF-Core deve condizer com a versão do SDK que você está utilizando.

> inclusive o EF está na última versão

> o projeto pois ele se encontra na versão 6.0.

Nesse caso, como o seu projeto está em 6.0, o EF Core precisa estar em 6.x.x.

Nas informações do pacote [no próprio Nuget] você consegue ver as dependências do pacote.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).